# Avoid copying memory for each subkernel

Tags: parallelization, memory

Here is a simplified example illustrating my issue;

```
G = GaussianMatrix[{1000, 1000}];

f[] := (
  n = RandomInteger[];
  n + Total[G, 2]
  )

ParallelTable[f[], {2}] (* two kernels *)
```

During the evaluation one needs two times the memory which is used for Table.
The variable G is duplicated for each subkernel although G remains unchanged.

How to avoid that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you need the same data to be transferred to each kernel?  In this simplied example the `Total` could be computed on the main kernel only *once* and only the result needs to be transferred.  I'm sure that your *real* problem is not that simple, but can you explain in more detail what sort of computation you are doing and precisely what data it needs?

Comment: I'm doing a particle tracking on a given vector field G (30gb memory) each subkernel computes one particle path with random initial position in this field G. I want to avoid G being copied since it is not necessary.

Comment: @Leon When you respond to comments, please address people using the `@` character, as I'm doing here.  Otherwise they don't get notified about the response and may never return to check.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for this hint!

Comment: @Leon Mathematica's parallel tools are limited and it is not possible to have even *read access* to the same data structure without duplicating it across kernels.  What you can do is create a function that retrieves only the information you need, and use `SetSharedFunction` on it.  This function will always be evaluated on the main kernel.  Calling it will be slow.  However, you will avoid data duplication.  If your algorithm is such that it doesn't spend most of its time in this function, this approach *might* work without a slowdown that is too significant. ...

Comment: ...  @Leon However if the function is called too often, then the parallel version will be slower than the serial one.

Comment: @Szabolcs This is a real pity that mathematica can't do parallel computing with large data. My rig consists of 16 cores with 128gb of ram but I can't use the power.

Comment: @Leon Can you parallelize elsewhere?  Or perhaps vectorize (operate on full arrays)?  There's another sort of parallelization available for `Compile`d functions.  It's much more limited but it also has much less overhead.  It might be used to parallelize some simple basic steps of the algorithm.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks! I will try to parallelize the computation of a single particle path.

Comment: What is your goal: simulate two particles or simulate many particles? If latter I recommend you to do it simultaneously. It allows you to use packed arrays and sometimes built-in threading (e.g. in matrix multiplication).

Comment: @ybeltukov Hello, yes I simulate thousands of particle paths. Each with NDSolve based on the field G as input.